# NullPointerException on HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement the following code:

```
    public class CheckSomeStaff extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private HttpURLConnection urlc;

    public boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {

        try {

            this.doInBackground();

            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                return true;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (isConnectingToInternet() == true) {

            try {
                urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(
                        "http://whatever.com/whatever_data_download/"
                                + "myDB.db").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(500);
                urlc.connect();
                urlc.getResponseCode();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
            }

            return null;

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

It works fine on emulator but when I am trying to download my application to device it trows out NullPointerException at the following line:

```
if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
```

Why does the null pointer occur on a device?

Comment: where are you calling hasActiveInternetConnection ? is it that call to isConnectingToInternet you have in doInBackground ?

Comment: urlc.setConnectTimeout(500); make the time 60000 and let me kow.

Comment: You should learn how to correctly use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I know that I have to learn AsyncTask and it is a process of learning. What am I doing wrong

Comment: for Andru, is this some kind of joke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
   public class CheckSomeStaff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    HttpURLConnection urlc;
    int result = -1;

    public boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {

        execute();
        while (result == -1) {
        }

        if (result == 200) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://whatever.com/whatever_data_download/" + "myDB.db").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(500);
            urlc.connect();
            return urlc.getResponseCode() == 200 ? true : false;

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        try {
            this.result = urlc.getResponseCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.result = -2;
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: And in my understanding without AsyncTask your code will not be implemented

Comment: There is big difference in your code and mine that you have put your code in back Ground thread and that's why you getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Ya I know that so you can use second approach wii

Comment: without putting in background thread it will not be implemented for API's higher then 8 (probably I am wrong).

Comment: isConnectingToInternet check connection, and it works OK. Why I am trying to implement doInBackground is to be sure that downloading connection is reachable

Comment: what is more interesting why it works on emulator but not on device

Comment: Thank you. give me some time.

Answer (score 2):

if this block

```
 if (isConnectingToInternet() == true) {
```

is false, the urlc is never initialized, thus you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: it is connected to Internet

Comment: is the doInBackground method actually executed in background? If so the call will return immediately and not initialize the variable.

Comment: I am trying execute suggestion from Biraj, but app hangs up and could not be implemented. Can you look through and give any ideas. Spasibo.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize "urlc" like-

```
URL url = new URL("Your URL");
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```